# Using object in ReactJS Context - method in object causes Property 'myMethod' does not exist on type 'unknown'

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I am trying to use a context for the first time where I have a Reactjs library which creates the context, and then in the main app updates the context and passes as a context provider within app.js.

In my library I have the following:

```
import * as React from "react";

export const MyContext = React.createContext(null);

export const MyContextProvider = MyContext.Provider;
export const MyContextConsumer = MyContext.Consumer;

export class MyClass
{
    constructor()
    {
        ....
    }

    ...

    myMethod(param1, param2 = null)
    {
        ...
    }
```

Then in my main project inside app.tsx I have the following:

```
const my_class = new MyClass();
my_class.initialise("param1", "param2", "param3");

<MyContextProvider value={my_class}>
          <ErrorBoundary>
              <BrowserRouter>
                  <Routes>
                      <Route index element={<Home />} />
                      <Route path='/blog' element={<BlogHome />} />
                      <Route path='/blog/:slug' element={<BlogPost />} />
                      <Route path='*' element={<NotFound />} />
                  </Routes>
              </BrowserRouter>
          </ErrorBoundary>
      </MyContextProvider>
```

Then in my child component in this case the `NotFound` component I then do the following:

```
const my_class = useContext(MyContext);
console.log("My class context", my_class);
my_class.myMethod(err, "Low");
```

This fails to compile as method `myMethod` throws an error `Property 'myMethod' does not exist on type 'unknown'`

When I remove the call to `myMethod` and just print `my_class` the object has everything that's been passed into the constructor, and I can see the method in there although it's within a [[Prototype]] object but not sure if that's expected or whether I should reference that in some way to access the method call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the issue was caused by a typescript issue within my main project.

Where I had `const my_class = useContext(MyContext)` I had to set the type of my_class by doing `const my_class : MyContext = useContext(MyContext)` resolves the issue

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but my guess is that you're not using your `MyContext` properly. That said, typically, context will be an object with properties and methods:

```js
value: {
  firstName: "Bob", // value from state
  lastName: "Smith", // value from state
  changeFirstName: () => {}, // some sort of state updater
  changeLastName: () => {}, // some sort of state updater
  otherCallback: () => {}, // some sort of callback that affects the UI
  ...etc
}
```

The above adheres to a more standard approach as values are coming from state (either from a shared state object or separated `useState` values) and some methods containing state setters to update these values accordingly. Since you're using the `useContext` hook, a functional programming (FP) approach would make more sense; however, it appears that you're trying to mix OOP (a plain class) with FP. Unless there's an absolute requirement to use a class, I'd recommend the  flat object approach above.

That said, here's how you can use a plain class within context...

Working Demo:

[image: Edit React Contextual Class]

Ideally, you'll want to initialize the context with class fields from where you're creating context:

```
import { createContext, useContext } from "react";
import User, { IUser } from "./User";

const user = new User("Bob", "Smith");
export const UserContext = createContext<IUser>(user);

export const useUserContext = () => useContext(UserContext);
```

Then, import `UserContext` context and the `useUserContext` hook and use them at the top level of your app:

```
import { UserContext, useUserContext } from "./UserContext";

const App = (): ReactElement => (
  <UserContext.Provider value={useUserContext()}>
    {...}
  </UserContext.Provider>
);

export default App;
```

In a child component, you can import the `useUserContext` hook and use its return value's fields/properties accordingly:

```
import { useUserContext } from "./UserContext";
import { ReactElement } from "react";

const Main = (): ReactElement => {
  const user = useUserContext();

  return (
    <main className="main">
      <h1>User Context</h1>
      <h2 className="user">
        <strong>First Name:</strong> {user.firstName}
      </h2>
      <h2 className="user">
        <strong>Last Name:</strong> {user.lastName}
      </h2>
      <h2 className="user">
        <strong>Combined Name:</strong> {user.combinedName()}
      </h2>
    </main>
  );
};

export default Main;
```

BUT THERE'S A PROBLEM WITH THIS APPROACH!

The problem you're going to run into is if you plan on manipulating/updating the fields within the class... React **won't** handle mutable field changes. So if you change a class field, that change **won't** re-render the app (as shown in the demo above).

Instead, you'll need to utilize **state** (either from a React `Component` class or a hook) and some sort of **callback that manipulates the state** (a callback that invokes `this.setState({...})` or a callback that invokes a `useState` state setter). Therefore, using a plain class within context really doesn't make much sense because it can only be statically stored/utilized.

Here's an example of how you can utilize state within context:

[image: Edit React Contextual State]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure why I would need to create a custom hook just to use the useContext hook, that seems unnecessary unless I'm missing something.

The context does appear to be working as console logging the context in the child component I can see all the details so it has everything set correctly, its just the method but this isn't typescript this library (my main project is though). I'm not worried about it updating state, once its initialised in app.js nothing changes that would affect how a component should render